# How to modify default WordPress registration form?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am creating one feature for adding user roles in WordPress default registration, it's working but I want to beautify it by adding a blank in user role selector, if it's showing a dropdown icon that will be awesome. I tried from my end but it's not showing.

My codes are: (enable 'anyone can register' here /wp-admin/options-general.php, to see the changes, now go to register /wp-login.php?action=register)

```
/*
show user profile in registeration
*/

//1. Add a new form element...
add_action('register_form', 'myplugin_register_form');
function myplugin_register_form()
{

    global $wp_roles;
    pll_e('Select Role');
    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ($wp_roles->roles as $key => $value) {
        // Exclude default roles such as administrator etc. Add your own
        if (!in_array($value['name'], ['Administrator', 'Editor'])) {
            echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

//2. Add validation.
add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3);
function myplugin_registration_errors($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email)
{

    if (empty($_POST['role']) || !empty($_POST['role']) && trim($_POST['role']) == '') {
        $errors->add('role_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a role.', 'mydomain'));
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register');
function myplugin_user_register($user_id)
{

    $user_id = wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST['role']));
}
```

Comment: _"I tried from my end"_ - where? I don't see it, in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is correct, change these lines from

```
echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
```

to

```
echo '<select name="role">';
```

this will give you a dropdown, without any conflict.

Now, these lines will give you a label

```
echo ('<label>Select Role</label>: &nbsp;');
```

Paste this in your code, as per your need.

Learn inputs, form fields here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp